# Android Studio newbie bundle passing

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm new to Android programming and have been watching videos but it's very slow. Hence I've decided the best way to learn is to start straight. I just want to do a simple passing of values from one activity to another but I'm not sure why it doesn't work as expected. If I pass a static value it works, but now I'm trying to pass a user input from a username/password input.

I picked the Navigation Drawer Activity - There's a Login page that user can key in username/password, and it gets sent to MainActivity. The main activity acts like a host to the 3 fragments - default is homeFragment and homeViewModel.

**In Login.java**

```
    public void LoginHandler(View target) {

        Intent myintent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("key1", "GFG :- Main Activity");

////        pass user input
        TextInputEditText username = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        TextInputEditText password = (TextInputEditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

        Log.i("print values", "Login Activity:TextInputEditText username is : " + username );

        String usernameText = username.getText().toString();
        String passwordText = password.getText().toString();

        Log.i("print values", "Login Activity:usernameText toString is : " + usernameText);

        bundle.putString("username", usernameText);
        bundle.putString("password", passwordText);

        Log.i("print values", "Login Activity: username and pw is: " + usernameText + " " + passwordText);

        myintent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(myintent);

    }
```

**In MainActivity.java**

```
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        Log.i("print values", "in On Create");

        String username = bundle.getString("usernameText");
        String password = bundle.getString("passwordText", "DefaultUsername");
        Log.i("print values", "Main Activity: TEST value is: " + bundle.getString("key1", "No value from the MainActivity"));


        Log.i("print values", "Main Activity: username and pw is: " + username + " " + password);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .setAction("Action", null).show();
            }
        });
        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        // Passing each menu ID as a set of Ids because each
        // menu should be considered as top level destinations.
        mAppBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(
                R.id.nav_home, R.id.nav_gallery, R.id.nav_slideshow)
                .setDrawerLayout(drawer)
                .build();
        NavController navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.nav_host_fragment);
        NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, navController, mAppBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);
    }
```

From the logs I can see "GFG :- Main Activity" which is hardcoded passes correctly. But the user input does not. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!!

```
2021-03-03 11:15:55.704 9230-9230/com.developer.tmx_android_v6 I/print values: Login Activity:TextInputEditText username is : com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText{adacf29 VFED..CL. ........ 282,382-1157,592 #7f080189 app:id/username}
2021-03-03 11:15:55.704 9230-9230/com.developer.tmx_android_v6 I/print values: Login Activity:usernameText toString is : usrname
2021-03-03 11:15:55.704 9230-9230/com.developer.tmx_android_v6 I/print values: Login Activity: username and pw is: usrname pw
2021-03-03 11:15:55.767 9230-9230/com.developer.tmx_android_v6 I/print values: in On Create
2021-03-03 11:15:55.768 9230-9230/com.developer.tmx_android_v6 I/print values: Main Activity: TEST value is: GFG :- Main Activity
2021-03-03 11:15:55.768 9230-9230/com.developer.tmx_android_v6 I/print values: Main Activity: username and pw is: null DefaultUsername
```

Comment: I see your code all work is done but the data is traveling through intent is key, value base.

Comment: you enter the intent  value in LoginHandler where you use (username,password) But when you recieved this data you will provide (usernameText,passwordText).Here is the problem make sure that the key is equal

Comment: if your key is not the same when you will not able to receive data

Answer (score 0):

you are putting key-value pair in a bundle with keys:

```
bundle.putString("username", usernameText);
    bundle.putString("password", passwordText);
```

But in MainActivity you are trying to retrieve them with different keys:

```
 String username = bundle.getString("usernameText");
    String password = bundle.getString("passwordText", "DefaultUsername");
```

Use the same keys in MainActivity you used while putting like so:

```
    String username = bundle.getString("username");
    String password = bundle.getString("password", "DefaultUsername");
```

Comment: Ah how silly of me. Thank you! Also I have a question about passing values through the host and fragments. What should be the best practice? I see there is shared preferences, bundle, intent. So now I can see it in the logs of MainActivity, but actually what I really want to do is show it as text it in Fragment of Home screen. Which java class should I be retrieving the value from? I tried adding it in HomeFragment before but I'm getting errors regarding getIntent()

Comment: I can currently retrieve it from HomeFragment using  "String username = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras().getString("username");" Is this the correct way to get it? ie. bundle creation on login page, and retrieve it directly from homefragment class.